# How to send a unix timestamp of specific time of day using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, timestamp, unix-timestamp

In React 18.2.0, i am trying to send a timestamp data of today's 00.00 AM (and if it's necessary GMT +03.00 timezone) in HTTP request. To do this, i'm keeping timestamp data in a state named `unixDate`. Then, i'm changing current timestamp with 00.00 AM and using `getTasks()` function to send timestamp data function. I've two more useEffect function to using `getTasks()`. One of them is just using getTasks() function but the other one is changing timestamp with another day by the number kept (`dateCounter` state is keeping integer number) and calling getTasks():

```
const [unixDate, setUnixDate] = useState(String(Math.floor(Date.now())));

  useEffect(() => {
    const today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setUnixDate(String(Math.floor(today)));
    getTasks();
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    getTasks();
  }, [handleAddTask])

useEffect(() => {
    const today = new Date();
    let tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + dateCounter)
    tomorrow.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setUnixDate(String(Math.floor(tomorrow / 1000)));
    getTasks();
  }, [dateCounter])

async function getTasks() {
    const data = await PostService.getStudentTasks(unixDate);
    setTask(data);
  }
```

When i'm running this code React gives me "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getTasks'. Either include it or remove the dependency array" warning all of the useEffects, doesn't change `unixDate` state with the 00.00 AM and running all of the useEffect code parts on page loading (`handleAddTask` and `dateCounter` useEffects should not be run).

And when i'm changing `dateCounter` state, `unixDate` state changing the before date at 00.00 AM.

I'm trying to fix that issue changed the getTasks() function like that:

```
async function getTasks(unixDate) {
    const data = await PostService.getStudentTasks(unixDate);
    setTask(data);
  }
```

The warnings are gone but this time getTasks() function using local unixDate variable and sending `undefined` unixDate.

How can i fix these issues?